# Angular JS - Not updating Message after http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Still new to Angular. I have tried `$scope.$apply();`, but this doesn't work with `$http`, so I tried `$watch`, but doesn't fix it.

This is my Msg HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"  ng-bind="ValidationContainer.SuccessMessages"></div>
```

This is my Angular JS Code:

```
$scope.ValidationContainer;

    $scope.sendForm = function () {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: formActionUrl,
            data: $scope.ViewModel
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.ValidationContainer = data.ValidationContainer;

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });

        $scope.$watch('ValidationContainer', function () {
            console.log('changed');
        });
    };
```

I can see that the Success Message is returned from the Server in Console:

[image]

But Message is always blank:

[image]

**EDIT**

**Console with data:**
[image]

**With Console.log**

```
$scope.sendForm = function () {

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: formActionUrl,
                data: $scope.ViewModel
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);

                $scope.ValidationContainer = data.ValidationContainer;

                console.log($scope.ValidationContainer);

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });

            $scope.$watch('ValidationContainer', function () {
                console.log('changed');
            });
        };
```

**EDIT 2**

Okay I got it to work like this (without `$watch` using `{{ }}` ):

```
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <ul ng-repeat="msg in ValidationContainer.SuccessMessages">
                    <li>{{msg.Message}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And Angular:

```
$scope.sendForm = function () {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: formActionUrl,
        data: $scope.ViewModel
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);

        $scope.ValidationContainer = data.ValidationContainer;

        console.log($scope.ValidationContainer);

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
};
```

**QUESTION 2: Isn't there are better way to display this without the** `ng-repeat`

Comment: There are no Console Errors.

Comment: I don't see a property `ValidationContainer` in that image.

Comment: what is the console log you used to print the above data ?

Comment: I have included a snapshot of my ViewModel and the console.log code @K.Toress

Comment: do you setup the angular with html page correctly ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're adding `ValidationContainer` to a `child scope` and trying to access it by it's `parent scope`. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yut02e8h/) as an example. You can quickly check this by changing `$scope` to `$rootScope`, then it should work. But keep in mind you should avoid `$rootScope` whenever possible.

Comment: @DieterGoetelen I managed to get it working without the $watch, using {{}}, but do I have to write a ng-repeat for this? Isn't there a better way to do it? Please see edit in my question.

Comment: It depends, if you always have one success message you can access it directly. If you have more you'll need to loop over the array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you want to display an object, that's not possible that way.

You have to do this :

```
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" ng-repeat="message in ValidationContainer.SuccessMessages" ng-bind="message.Message"></div>
```

It will display the string

Comment: yup, ng-bind did not accept the [0] as I hoped. that's why I added the ng-repeat. For your second question, if you only have 1 message at a time, modify the object controller-side. If not, create a new topic on this site

Comment: I might have more than one SuccessMessage at a time. But I was looking for something in one line (like in your answer), instead of the 5 lines solution in my question.

Comment: build the string into a for loop inside your controller, simplest way of doing it, and probably the better. Although, At your place, I would create a custom directive that receives your object in input, and then displays it